# Как осуществить mpeg dash (или HLS) стриминг через Javascript?

Tags: javascript, streaming, hls

Мне нужно не воспроизводить стрим, а именно отправлять поток на сервер, используя javascript. Я пытался нагуглить решение, но все предлагают стриминг через ffmpeg/obs/gstream. Есть ли какие-нибудь js библиотеки для этого?

Comment: Во-первых, HLS и MPEG-DASH в принципе не предназначены для отправки потока. Во-вторых, видимо нужно копать в сторону WebRTC

Comment: Получается, по ссылке ниже человек использует ffmepg, который передает по rtmp видео, и там уже nginx обрабатывает в нужный формат, верно?

https://isrv.pw/html5-live-streaming-with-mpeg-dash

Comment: Верно. Но если вас интересует javascript в браузере, то никакого rtmp в нём нет

Comment: Спасибо большое, показали куда копать)